# Unexpected behaviour with a tmacro in Julia

Tags: multithreading, macros, julia

I was recently playing around with using macros to write functions in Julia. While it worked fine for serial codes, I stumbled upon an unexpected error when making a nested loop inside of a macro-generated functions threaded with `@threads`. As far as I can tell, the loop `m = 1:M` in the code example below is not properly assigned to the different threads when the function is generated from a macro.

I've uploaded a minimal code that reproduces is:

```
using Base.Threads

macro macro_test(funcname)
    fname = esc(funcname)
    quote
        function $(fname)(vals, M, N)
            @threads:static for m = 1:M
                for n = 1:N
                    println("  threadid = $(threadid()); m = $m; n = $n")
                    vals[n,m] = n*m
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function func_test(vals, M, N)
    @threads:static for m = 1:M
        for n = 1:N
            println("  threadid = $(threadid()); m = $m; n = $n")
            vals[n,m] = n*m
        end
    end
end

function main()
    M = 3
    N = 3
    println("Normal function:")
    vals1 = zeros(Int64, N, M)
    func_test(vals1, M, N)
    println("Macro function:")
    vals2 = zeros(Int64, N, M)
    @macro_test(loop_test)
    loop_test(vals2, M, N)
    println("Test results:")
    for m = 1:M
        for n = 1:N
            v1 = vals1[n,m]
            v2 = vals2[n,m]
            check = v1 == v2
            println("  $v1 $v2 $check")
        end
    end
end

main()
```

Which if I try to run using `julia -t 2` produces the following output

```
Normal function:
  threadid = 1; m = 1; n = 1
  threadid = 1; m = 1; n = 2
  threadid = 1; m = 1; n = 3
  threadid = 1; m = 2; n = 1
  threadid = 1; m = 2; n = 2
  threadid = 1; m = 2; n = 3
  threadid = 2; m = 3; n = 1
  threadid = 2; m = 3; n = 2
  threadid = 2; m = 3; n = 3
Macro function:
  threadid = 1; m = 1; n = 1
  threadid = 2; m = 3; n = 1
  threadid = 2; m = 3; n = 2
  threadid = 2; m = 3; n = 3
  threadid = 1; m = 3; n = 2
  threadid = 1; m = 3; n = 3
  threadid = 1; m = 2; n = 1
  threadid = 1; m = 2; n = 2
  threadid = 1; m = 2; n = 3
Test results:
  1 0 false
  2 0 false
  3 0 false
  2 2 true
  4 4 true
  6 6 true
  3 3 true
  6 6 true
  9 9 true
```

So for some reason, `m=3` is assigned to both of the threads when the function was generated from a macro, whereas the "normal" function behaves as I would expect. Is this expected behaviour?